# Gravitational redshift of temperature and electrostatic potential

Tags: general-relativity, electrostatics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, gravitational-redshift

Consider a charged black hole in four-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, with charge $Q$, mass $M>Q$:

$ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2+r^2d\Omega_2^2$, with

$f(r)=1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}$.

When an observer at radial coordinate $r_1$ emits a photon, an observer at radial coordinate $r_2>r_1$ will perceive the photon with a redshifted wavelength. This is easy to interpret.

A similar thing happens for the temperature. If $\kappa$ is the surface gravity of the black hole, then the Hawking temperature is $T_H=\frac{\kappa}{2\pi}$. Due to gravitational redshift, the temperature measured by an observer at radial coordinate $r$ is

$T_{loc}(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(r)}}T_H$.

The redshift factor is the same as for a redshifted frequency, which I can understand by associating temperature with the inverse imaginary time period.

I interpret this redshift as a consequence of the particles which constitute Hawking radiation experiencing gravitational redshift. **Is this correct?**

Apparently, something similar also happens for the electrostatic potential. The electrostatic potential difference between the outer event horizon $r_+$ and infinity is given by $\Phi=\frac{Q}{r_+}$. However, the electrostatic potential between $r_+$ and some coordinate $r>r_+$, "blueshifted" from infinity to $r$, is given by

$\phi(r)=\left(\frac{Q}{r_+}-\frac{Q}{r}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(r)}}$.

(*Source: Braden, Brown, Whiting and York, Charged black hole in a grand canonical ensemble, PRL Vol. 42 No. 10, 1990, equation 4.15.*)

This expression seems to tell me that $\frac{Q}{r_+}-\frac{Q}{r}$ is the electrostatic potential difference between $r$ and $r_+$ as measured by someone at infinity, and the above expression is this same potential difference as measured by someone at $r$.

> Is there a simple interpretation why the measured electrostatic potential
>   should experience gravitational redshift as well, with the same redshift factor as a frequency? What is the
>   wavelength that is being redshifted in this case, is it the one from
>   the photons mediating the electromagnetic force? (These photons are virtual though, so can they actually be redshifted?)

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the paper to hand, but by $\phi$ the authors could mean either $A_0$ or $A^0$, and these differ by a factor of $f(r)$.